# Как подключиться к веб ресурсу из андроид приложения?

Tags: java, android

Дали тестовое задание : разработать андроид-приложение, которое будет подключаться к новостному ресурсу (ria.ru) и закачивать в кэш оттуда данные.
Я относительный новичок в программировании и знаком только с Java SE.
Пытался гуглить по направлению веб сервисов для андроид но ничего не смог найти.

Дайте пожалуйста совет, что конкретно нужно искать чтобы наладить такое взаимодействие между приложением и веб ресурсом? Какие технологии можно/нужно для этого использовать?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
URL url = new URL("http://ria.ru");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()));

String tmp;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) sb.append(tmp);

String html = sb.toString();
```

Потом можно с помощью regex вытащить данные из html.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ, но это нормальная практика или костыль?
я потому спрашиваю, что html это же xml - в плане того, что не такой строгий и некоторые теги могут отсутствовать

Comment: Если у сайта есть свое API, то тогда в этом случае лучше использовать этот API. Если API у сайта нет, то тогда это вполне можно использовать.

Answer (score 2):

Парсить страницы. Для изображений рекомендую picasso.